# Magento showing inactive categories in topmenu

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

In my CMS I have disabled a bunch of categories from appearing in my nav (see screenshot below), but the categories still appear in my topmenu block.

Here is the code in my page/html/topmenu.phtml file - what do I need to change to stop these categories from appearing?

I am using Magento CE 1.7

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top');?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [i.imm.io](http://i.imm.io/xV8Y.png))</sub>

[edit]

When I do

```
foreach(Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories() as $c)
{
  $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($c->getId());
  var_dump($cat->getIncludeInMenu());
}
```

all the categories return 1, despite two root categories being set to no in the admin panel.

I have caching turned off and cleared, and I have reindexed my categories and products multiple times.

I know the option is being saved into the db because when I browse away and back again the option is still set to "no", which suggests the problem is with the category model either loading or reporting the option wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set up multiple stores. Each store had their own duplicate set of values for each category and product field. What I had been doing was altering the default values, which were being ignored in the individual store views. To resolved, I had to change the store view (located at the top/left of the admin section) THEN set the field value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line instead:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>
```

renderCategoriesMenuHtml checks to see if the category is active.

Comment: That throws an exception. I am unable to locate the function in Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu.

Comment: Hmm.. They must have changed it in 1.7. Sorry